# Google Cloud Armor options with Network load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I am working with Google Network Load balancer hosting an application. I need to enable Cloud Armor security policies for the NLB backend as target. I am currently using the Standard tier of Cloud Armor. The documentation says standard tier supports for NLB but it also says to use Network Edge security policy. But that is available only in Plus tier. If anyone could clear my doubt on how to integrate NLB with Cloud armor it would be helpful.

I tried to restrict access via Google firewall. But I am unable to restrict the access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, the Cloud Armor NLB option is only available to customers that have purchased a Cloud Armor Managed Protection subscription. It is not available as a stand alone option in the Standard Cloud Armor billing model.  There is no way around it today.